# Any packages contain Labeled-LDA implementation in R

Tags: r, lda, topic-modeling

I am working on supervised topic models with R; There is multi-thousand-word document which have labels for, and I want to design a application to automatic assign labels to new documents. I am using R to test algorithm and select the best one.

My Question is: **Is there any R package which implement Labeled-LDA?**
by the way: I have tried packages: `tm`,  `topicmodel`, `lda` and `RTextTools`, and tried some algorithms, e.g. SVM LDA

Comment: You can search CRAN for what you're looking for with the `sos` package. `library(sos);findFn('LDA')`

Comment: The difficulty one faces with Matthew's suggestion (which would normally be helpful and my suggestion as well)  is that "LDA" in the questioner's mind is Latent Dirichlet Analysis rather than what is arguably the more common use in statistics, Linear Discriminant Analysis.